# tmadmin psr response : can't get temp file for writing

Tags: oracle, tuxedo

i've got a problem with my local tuxedo instalation. My servers and services works fine but when i try to list them using psr (printserver) or printclient tmadmin response: pg: Can't get temp file for writing. Can you tell me where can i find possible issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was no space i /var mounted place.

Answer (score 0):

did you look at the error messages for tuxedo found in this location

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13203_01/tuxedo/tux71/pdf/cdtux_d.pdf

Comment: Yes, but i don't get any error number. None of them suits to mine. The problem occurs even when i try 'help' command. Shutdown, crdl, boot works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're facing problem with the ULOG, have you setted up ULOGPFX and it address a location with the sufficient permissions?